# Couldn't found resource file 'rights'

Tags: delphi

In FormCreate procedure I write:

```
 var f: TResourceStream;
  begin
    // load data about rights from rights.txt resource file
     f := TResourceStream.create(Hinstance, 'rights', PChar('RT_RCDATA'));
  try
    LoadFromStream(f);
  finally
    f.free;
  end;
```

and get error:

```
Project1.exe raised exception class ERESNotFound with message 'Resource rights not found'.
```

if I change file path 'rights' on:

```
'rights.txt'            or
'D:\Example\rights.txt' or
'D:\Example\rights'
```

I get the same error!

rights.txt file I locate both in project folder and in win32\debug\project1.exe folder but the same error occurs.

**UPDATE 1**

[PopupMenu with access rights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCK6S.png)

[rights.txt file for loading popupmenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rJuQ.png)

what would be these undefined simbols in rights.txt file?

Comment: You have to compile RC data to Res with either the resource compiler or on later delphi versions this can be handled through the Project, Resources menu I believe it is, you have done that first haven't you?

Comment: I enter in "Project"-->"Resources and images" and add 'rights.txt' file to resouces but no row appear in project file after uses. I only see {$R *.res} and the same error appear.
Delphi version: 10.1 Berlin

Comment: I already see 'rights.txt' file in Project manager but the same error appear.

Comment: @Delphi159: "*no row appear in project file after uses*" - it does for me. The "Resources and Images" dialog adds items to the `.dproj` file (not the `.dpr` file), and then those items get compiled into the resources of the final executable. "*I already see 'rights.txt' file in Project manager*" - items in the "Resources and Images" dialog do appear in the Project Manager.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the `ResType` Parameter to `RT_RCDATA` instead of `PChar('RT_RCDATA')`

```
f := TResourceStream.create(Hinstance, 'rights', RT_RCDATA);
```

The `RT_RCDATA` defined in `System.Types` unit as follow

```
const
  RT_RCDATA       = PChar(10);
```

So you can also use it like this

```
f := TResourceStream.create(Hinstance, 'rights', PChar(10));
```

Comment: If you are going to specify a resource type directly instead of using a predefined constant, you should be using `MakeIntResource()` instead, eg: `f := TResourceStream.create(Hinstance, 'rights', MakeIntResource(10));`

Comment: I have 'rights.txt' file. in 'notapad++' I rename it to 'rights.rc'. Then in "Project"--"Resource and images" I add .rc file to Project and {$R 'rigths.res' 'rigths.rc'} appear in Project1.dpr file. After that pressing "ctrl+F9" and I get an error: "bad characters in source input". 
there are lots of non-printing characters in 'rights.txt file', such as: STX, SOH, GS etc.

Comment: @Delphi159 Keep the file extension as is (`.txt`) or rename it to something else rather than `.rc` and add it to the Resource and images as `RCData` **Resource Type**  there, Do not forget to remove the `rights.rc` file from the **Project Manager**

Comment: @RepeatUntil I remove old rights.rc file ,  keep rights.txt file and add it in 'Resource and images' but the same error.  Then save it as rights.rc and he same error. Notepad opens .rc file as usual, but delphi gets error  "bad characters in source input" and opens it in this view 14C8EDF2E5F0F4E5 E9F120E4E8F1EFE5 F2F7E5F0E0000200.......

Comment: @RemyLebeau I change PChar('RT_RCDATA') on MakeIntResource(10) but nothing changed.

Comment: I think the method of *loading* the resource is not the problem here. Rather, it's the method of *linking* the resource that's the problem. I think this person has not created a proper RC file, but instead just took the text resource and naively renamed it with an rc extension, expecting it to magically become a resource.

Comment: @RobKennedy yes, since the OP said as much. Renaming the `.txt` file as-is to `.rc` is wrong. An `.rc` file needs to reference the `.txt` file, not BE the `.txt` file. But, there is no need for an `.rc` file at all when using the "Resources and Images" dialog. The referenced items are compiled directly into the executable resources, same as if an `.rc` file were compiled into a `.res` and then linked into the executable.

Comment: @RobKennedy,  I update my post and add examples of .txt and .rc files

Comment: @RemyLebeau I update my post and add examples of .txt and .rc files

Comment: @Delphi159 please don't host files on external sites. Copy/paste the actual text into your question directly. But again, you DO NOT need an `.rc` file when using the "Resources and Images" dialog, everything needed to link the file into the executable is handled for you.